# Packages of OPAM remote can be searched but not installed

Tags: ocaml, opam

I've set up a custom OPAM repository, for the needs of the company I'm working for.

It can be accessed through SSH.

Here is the command I used to add the remote :

```
opam remote add company-repo ssh://git@host:port/repo.git
```

I get the following error when trying to install my packages:

```
$ opam install <package>
Your request can't be satisfied:
  - No package matches <package>.

No solution found, exiting
```

This is awkward because I can see them using `opam search ...`.

Am I missing something in the process?

**EDIT**

I can install my packages properly on my dev environment, using `opam pin`. I only have the problem with the production repository.

**EDIT 2**

- I do have run `opam update`.
- I'm using OPAM 1.2.0.
- Sadly verbose mode returns me nothing more than the previous listing.

Running `opam remote` returns me the following listing:

```
$ opam remote
10 [git]      company     ssh://git@host:port/opam-repository.git
0  [http]     default     https://opam.ocaml.org
```

BTW: what is the meaning of the numbers in the first column of this listing? Priority ?

Comment: First of all, have you run `opam update`? What is your opam version? What is the output of `opam remote`? Have you tried to run it with `-v` and `-d` flags to get more hints?

Comment: @ivg I've added the information you requested in a second edit.

Comment: are you sure that you've chosen a correct protocol? According to url it looks more like a git, maybe `git://` is a proper solution. Again, there is not enough information about how you set up your repository. As usual, after `git remote` command you should receive a bunch of output. 
BTW, yes it is indeed the priority

Comment: Does `opam show <package>` works? Are your package marked as compatible with your current OCaml version? Are there any malformed dependences?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error and the issue was that there was a typo in one dependency of the `<package>` (see `opam` file). That could be a path to explore...